# Angular Slider - html I need to add a left and right margin

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using the Angular-slider
    http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-slider.

Everything works with one exception - I cannot get the slider bar to conform to the margins.

My goal is to have the slider in the center of the page padded on each side with about 20% white space on each side.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
 ....
  <div style="margin: 40px 0 60px 0; font-size: 10pt;">
        <div style="width:20px">
       <a style="text-align: left; margin-left: 20%;margin-right: 20%">
        <slider floor="0" ceiling="500" step="50" precision="2" ng-model="cost"></slider>
           </a>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but you can try to set:

```
position: relative;
left: 20%;
right: 20%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you trying to do that and styling the `<a>` element, but from the code in Angular's page you should use something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <p>Cost: </p> 
        <slider floor="100" ceiling="1000" step="50" precision="2" ng-model="item.cost"></slider>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so, to adapt to your case:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <p>Cost: </p> 
        <slider floor="100" ceiling="1000" step="50" precision="2" ng-model="item.cost"></slider>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now, the CSS is as easy as this:

```
.container{text-align:center}
ul{width:60%; margin:20px auto} /* adjust vertical margins to your needs */
li{....}
```

Note that this example use a construction of `UL` and `LI`, but you can obviously replace it with `DIV` using the same logic. Not sure why you want an `A`, but try it out, maybe it works, I just don't understand teh need and probably need more information.

Comment: The <a> is not necessary, I added it while trying to fix the issue. The slider control uses a span so I wrapped it in the <a> so I could set the width- This did make a slight difference but didn't fix my issue.